# QueryDSL: Is it possible to add fields to SELECT statement dynamically?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, querydsl

I want to automate SQL statement creation for Oracle, and I've been looking into QueryDSL. I've been successful in creating a query with static columns using the code below.

My aim is to feed in a list of columns into QueryDSL and have them added to the SELECT statement. This would require a new object being created, then added to the SELECT statement and repeated for each column in the list.

From the documentation, it doesn't look like I can add more columns to the SELECT statement after it's been instantiated. I've only been able to create the SELECT statement once; any additional SELECT statements override the previous.

```
QDRnccell rnccell = new QDRnccell("rnccell");
FTnn0000xxx t032 = new QFTnn0000xxx("t032");
StringPath cellname = Expressions.stringPath(rnccell, "cellname");

SQLQuery sqlQuery = new SQLQuery(conn, configuration);
sqlQuery
    .select(t032.starttime,
        t032.cyyy.as("tp_0"),
        t032.czzz.as("tp_1"))
    .from(t032);
```

I was hoping to add additional columns to the select statement after the sqlQuery was created but as mentioned before, it just gets overwritten.

Comment: Have you tried calling `sqlQuery.select(t032.somethingElse)` after the initial statement and before execution?

Comment: @RobertBain Thanks for the suggestion. I had tried this but unfortunately the 2nd call replaces the 1st call (ie only the fields in the 2nd call are queried).

Comment: Did you get any solutions to this so far?